# How to create the "Use-Case" Diagram by means of EMF

Tags: eclipse, uml, emf, uml-designer

simple question.

Why Eclipse Modelling Framework doesn't support Use-Case diagram ?

There are many diagrams, but no use-case:

[image]

also, i study the tutorial at [Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF) - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEMF/article.html) and just created a "Ecore Modelling Project". I was not able to create any "Use-case" diagram.

thanks for reply

Comment: Maybe I missed something EMF should aloow you to create Ecore diagram and that's all. Activity, Class, Component, Use cases diagrams are UML diagrams that's another level.

Comment: @RedBeard thanks a lot. I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the goal of EMF is to specify modeling languages, like activity or class diagrams. Editors for the UML language have been implemented based on the capabilities of EMF, such as the [Papyrus](http://eclipse.org/papyrus), [MagicDraw](http://docs.nomagic.com/display/MD182/UML+Model+Implementation+Using+EMF) or [UML Designer](http://obeonetwork.github.io/UML-Designer/) tools (but there are others as well). Assuming you are looking for an UML modeler, you should look at the specific Eclipse-based UML tools.

EMF on the other hand provides a few modeling languages that ease the definition of other modeling languages, most notable the ones called 'Ecore' and 'Generator model'.

It is possible to install both EMF and concrete modeling languages in the same Eclipse installation, but they have very different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that in your Eclipse you have installed:

- [Ecore Tools](https://www.eclipse.org/ecoretools/) which allows you to create Ecore diagrams
- [UML Designer](http://www.umldesigner.org/) which allows you to create UML diagrams

The [Activity Explorer](http://www.umldesigner.org/ref-doc/define-the-system.html#Dashboard) you see is provided by UML Designer and so it is there to create UML diagrams only.
I think that you use UML Designer 7.0 and there was an [issue](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/887) with it about the activity explorer which opens even for non UML project. Now this issue is fixed in the 7.1 version of UML Designer.
To find how to create new diagrams with Ecore Tools you can have a look to the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.emf.ecoretools.doc/doc/EcoreTools%20User%20Manual.html?cp=17_0_0_2#CreatingdiagramsfromanexistingEcore).